# Synchronous baud rate (RFC2217) encode/decode

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, rs485

I'm trying to implement RFC2217 in my code but I can't understand how the last parity bit (46H and 28H) is generated.

I'm using RS485 to Ethernet device.

What will be the code, if I'm using 2400,E,8,1?

Is it: `55 AA 55 09 60 1B XX`?

- Is `1B` right?
- What will be `XX`?

User manual: page 42 in https://www.sarcitalia.it/file_upload/prodotti//USR-N520-Manual-EN-V1.0.4.pdf

[image: Synchronous baud rate (RFC2217) picture SS]

Comment: With that specification, the number of bytes in the baud rate will be less than one byte. Aside from the last parity byte, this should be the case. `55 AA 55 00 09 60 1B XX` So `1B` would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the field for the baud rate you missed the MSByte. This field shall be `00 09 60`.
2. Yes, `1B` for "E,8,1" is correct. BTW, the table lists 2 bits for the 1-bit fields of "stop bit" and "parity enable", which is quite irritating.
3. The field "parity" is actually just a sum, without the header and the MSBit cleared. (I don't grasp the text of the explanation, but the document seems to be low quality anyway.)

   `01 C2 00 03`: 0x01 + 0xC2 + 0x00 + 0x03 = 0xC6; without bit 7 = 0x46.

   `00 25 80 03`: 0x00 + 0x25 + 0x80 + 0x03 = 0xA8; without bit 7 = 0x28.

   Your telegram `00 09 60 1B`: 0x00 + 0x09 + 0x60 + 0x1B = 0x84; without bit 7 = 0x04. So `XX` is `04`.